# Uploading photo along with other info from form using angular.js and node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ng-file-upload

Need help with uploading photo and saving it to local folder using node.js, express and angular for front end. Form is done and saving new user information to mongoose works fine. Need to add the photo upload part.
NOTE: I've gone through every tutorial there is, but I don't seem to be able to integrate or use any of them with what I've already built. Please help!

My project structure looks like this - 
[Project folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFrhe.png)

**controller file for registration form (node.js backend) (api/controllers/user.controller.js) -**

```
module.exports.register = function(req, res){

  // Create new user 
  console.log("Registering Users");
  var email = req.body.email;
  var fname = req.body.fname;
  var lname = req.body.lname;
  var password = req.body.password;

  User.create({
      email: email,
      fname: fname,
      lname: lname,
      password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10))
    }, function(err, user){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).json(err);
      } else {
        console.log("User created", user);
        res.status(201).json(user);
      }
    }
  );
};
```

**index.js file (node.js back end routing) (api/routes/index.js) -**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var ctrlUsers = require('../controllers/users.controller.js');

router
  .route('/register')
  .post(ctrlUsers.register);

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js file (angular.js front-end) (public/angular-app/app.js)**

```
angular.module('login', ['ngRoute']).config(config);

function config($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/angular-app/register/register.html',
      controller: 'RegisterController',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
  })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
}
```

**controller file for registration form (angular.js front-end) (public/angular-app/register/register.controller.js) --**

```
angular.module('login').controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);

function RegisterController($http){
  var vm = this;

  vm.register = function(){
    var user = {
      email: vm.email,
      fname: vm.fname,
      lname: vm.lname,
      password: vm.password
    };

    if(!vm.email || !vm.password){
      vm.error = 'Please enter an email and password.';
    } else {
      if(vm.password !== vm.passwordRepeat){
        vm.error = 'Please enter matching passwords.';
      } else {
        console.log(user);
        $http.post('/api/register', user).then(function(result){
          console.log(result);
          console.log(user);
          vm.message = 'Successful login! Hello,' + ' ' + vm.fname + ' ' + vm.lname + '.';
          vm.error= '';
        }).catch(function(error){
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
    }
  }
};
```

**Registration form HTML file - (public/angular-app/registration/registration.html)**

```
<h1>Welcome!</h1>

<div ng-if="vm.message" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
  <p>{{ vm.message }}</p>
  <img ngf-src="vm.profilePicture" ngf-size="{width:200, height:200, quality:1.0}"/>
</div>

<div ng-if="vm.error" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  <p>{{ vm.error }}</p>
</div>

<form ng-hide="vm.message" name="register" ng-submit="vm.register()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="eg. john.smith@example.com" ng-model="vm.email" autocapitalize="none"/>
  </div>

...some other fields...

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="profilePicture">Upload Photo</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="profilePicture" ng-model="vm.profilePicture"/>
  </div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: use formData to upload

Answer (score 0):

Using FormData :

```
var formData = new FormData()
formData.append("profilePicture",vm.profilePicture);
formData.append("email",vm.email);
formData.append("fname",vm.fname);
formData.append("lname",vm.lname);
formData.append("password",vm.password);

 $http.post('/api/register', formData).then(function(result){
          console.log(result);
          console.log(user);
          vm.message = 'Successful login! Hello,' + ' ' + vm.fname + ' ' + vm.lname +'.';
          vm.error= '';
        }).catch(function(error){
          console.log(error);
        });
```